# Allow access to sharepoint has some users just the week

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, access

Is there a way to block the use of SharePoint for multiple users on the weekend and allow them to enter only during the work week?

Comment: I believe the only way to restrict it is if you are using dirsync to synchronize your AD and then using something like ADFS to put logon restrictions in place.

Comment: I don't use dirsync :/ I understand that there is not any solution :/

Comment: you'd like to restrict them access only to SharePoint or to entire Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the **User Policy at WebApplication level**.

Write powershell script (for exemple)  Who add 'All Authenticated users' for all zone of your webAppication with the **Deny ALL** Permissions for weekend 
And Remove this rule for working days

Comment: No WebApplication or zones for SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad solution, but only one that comes to my mind without ADFS.

You can remove their permissions by removing security group and then re-adding the group. SharePoint Online groups and users can be removed and added using Powershell, so you could automate it into a script running at certain hours. Please check:
[Add-SPOUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161371.aspx)

> Adds an existing Office 365 user or an Office 365 **security group** to a
>   SharePoint group.

[Remove-SPOUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161381.aspx)

> Removes a user or **a security group** from a site collection or a group.

Comment: if you remove SPuser from the site, the user will lost all custom permission (positioned at SPListItem for exemple). And will never recover their old right after re-add him

Comment: Agreed. That's why I started with 'it's a bad solution'. It sounded better than nothing, 'coz otherwise there is no way. But thanks for pointing this out.